# Jest mock with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have this simple test file:

```js
describe('index', () => {
    it('should bootstrap the app', async () => {
        const root = <div />;
        jest.spyOn(ReactDOM, 'render');
        ...
        ReactDOM.render.mockImplementationOnce(() => {} );
        ...
        ReactDOM.render.mockRestore();
    } );
} );
```

I get the following typescript error: "TS2339: property 'mockImplementationOnce' does not exist on type 'Renderer'"

Anyone knows how I can make TypeScript recognize jest mock methods?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to hint typescript that `render` is a [SpyInstance](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts)

```
const render = ReactDOM.render as any as SpyInstance;
render.mockImplementationOnce(() => { });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ReactDOM.render` which doesn't have the proper type, use the returned value of `jest.spyOn(ReactDOM, 'render')` which is a Jest mock function (cf. [`spyOn()` doc](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname)) i.e. with the expected type for TypeScript, including both methods `mockImplementationOnce()` and `mockRestore()`.

```js
const reactRenderMock = jest.spyOn(ReactDOM, 'render');
// ...
reactRenderMock.mockImplementationOnce(() => {} );
// ...
reactRenderMock.render.mockRestore();
```

Comment: What of the case of an automocked function? This was just as example. Say I import `getUsers`, which is automocked, how do I achieve this without using `...as any`

Comment: @Kizer: how a function is automocked? Can you give a code example?

Comment: @Kizer: do you mean using `jest.fn()`? It's returned value also has the right type for TypeScript.